# call to undefined function fatal error - weird problem

Tags: routes

I have a custom module which calls a custom function. I created this function longback working fine till yesterday. today it says call to undefined function
fatal error. Does anyone know what the reason could be. I tried all the possibility to make it work, but it crashes!
using drupal 7 , php 5.2

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the module?

Comment: Is this function in main module or some inc file?

Comment: Please add more info to your question. Where is the custom function written ? Where are you calling this from ? Are the custom modules enabled ?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) in its current form this isn't a reasonable question. It's impossible to speculate as to what's causing errors in code we can't see. Please add the code and exact error message(s) to the question, and flag it to be reviewed for re-opening

Answer (score 2):

The reasons maybe:

1. Either the module is disabled.
2. Typo error in the function call.
3. The module has been removed.